# How do you reduce variables for multiple multivariate linear regression

Tags: python, python-3.x, sas, statistics, linear-regression

I have 24 factors which have been transformed to 370 variables which then need to be modelled in a 4-factor multivariate linear regression model (need to produce a list of 4-factor models).

What is a best way to reduce the run-time? Is there a way to reduce the variables? Is k-means clustering the best technique to apply

I will also need to do the same for producing a list of 2-factor and 3-factor multivariate linear regression models

Is there an equivalent package in python like Proc Varclus in SAS?

Comment: nothing to do with pandas. removing the tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look more into [PCA](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html), Principal component analysis, which is usually done to reduce dimensions that have the greatest variance. As for KNN clustering it really depends on your data and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Is PCA the way to reduce the run time? Like it is to kind of grouping variables ?

Comment: It can potentially reduce the run-time, however I would caution against using it if you have no idea what your data set is about. PCA is one of the more common ways to reduce the features into lesser features by projecting it on a "common" line. You should probably research more into how to pre-process your data before applying the ML algorithms.

Comment: My features are essentially macroeconomic timeseries. I have transformed all the columns (Variables) based on a time period that I am supposed to build regression for. But since having 370 variables - its extremely inefficient to run a 4 factor linear regression from here on these 370 variables. Looking for something efficient to reduce runtime and output an intuitive list of models